# Are there apps for [near] real-time collaborative programming in JavaScript?

Tags: collaboration

I'd like to take part in, or host an event where I collaboratively code something with a small group of people in geographically dispersed locations.

Is there a web app like [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that allows near-real-time editing and code sharing? I'm thinking of the sort of editing you see in Google docs spreadsheets, where the cursors and editing of other people editing the spreadsheet are shown to the other editors/viewers in near-real-time.

Comment: Either google PubSub(Hub), look for node.js or simply make a google+ hangout app.

Comment: Those are all programming solutions... the OP was looking for an existing web application.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [TypeWith.Me](http://typewith.me/) to set up a pad that up to 8 people can edit live at the same time.

There are many other Etherpad knock offs that utilize the code base released by Etherpad when they were acquired by Google.

Comment: Nice, and I can see some of the Google Wave and Google Docs style interaction and collaboration, but there's no facility for JavaScript that I'm probably more interested in than the real-time editing. Good find though, so +1.

Comment: TypeWith.Me is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bespin to edit code collaboratively](https://mozillalabs.com/blog/2009/08/bespin-0-4-stop-collaborate-and-code/).

Comment: This is as close as I've seen, but I could just use Google Docs to do the same. If they had the ability to execute code immediately then this would be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is the good old SubEthaEdit that is very good at this sort of thing:

You could also check out Bespin at mozillalabs.

There's links in the old Etherpad site.

There's also WriteBoard - put a dot com at the end of this.

But you know - regular old Google Docs now has this support right?

And here's my one link:

http://playground.html5rocks.com/

Comment: Have a look also at [Code](http://www.panic.com/coda/) - it uses the SubEthaEdit engine